NGINX proxy issue with configuration. Switching between default page and my app
I'm working with NGINX as a reverse proxy for an APP in docker.
The problem that I'm facing is that, when I reload my website, it switches between 404 and my App on docker. I have tried a lot of changes to the conf. but nothing really works. Can you help me figure out what's wrong ?
I think it has something to do with types of HTTP requests, as HTTP/1.0 is the one that breaks and gives a 404, while HTTP/1.1 does not. Based on access and error logs:
Access logs:
ipadress - - time "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1196 ......"
ipadress - - time "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 555  ......
ipadress - - time "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555  ......
ipadress - - time "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1196 ......"
ipadress - - time "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 555  ......
ipadress - - time "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555  ......
ipadress - - time "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1196 ......"

Error logs
time [error] 23944#22920: *172 "c:\Nginx/html/index.html" is not found (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost"
time [error] 23944#22920: *173 "c:\Nginx/html/index.html" is not found (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost"
time [error] 23944#22920: *174 "c:\Nginx/html/index.html" is not found (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost"
time [notice] 17016#18872: signal process started
time [error] 23944#22920: *175 "c:\Nginx/html/index.html" is not found (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost"
time [error] 23944#22920: *176 "c:\Nginx/html/index.html" is not found (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost"


nginx.conf
events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}

http {
    error_log logs/error.log;
    server {
        listen       80;
        if ($server_protocol = 'HTTP/1.0') {
            return 400 "HTTP/1.0 requests are not supported";
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

My App on docker
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  const requestData = {
    method: req.method,
    url: req.url,
    headers: req.rawHeaders,
    ip:req.socket.remoteAddress
  };
  res.end(`<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            Hello from Node.js in Docker!
            This request headers are:
            ${JSON.stringify(req.headers, null, 2)}
            All request can be explored:
            Method<br>
            ${JSON.stringify(requestData.method)}
            Url<br>
            ${JSON.stringify(requestData.url)}
            ip<br>
            ${JSON.stringify(requestData.ip)}
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>`);
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});


My dockerfile
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]

